# http запрос в ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, http, ionic

У меня есть страница авторизации. Опуская получение данных и обработку формы, перейдем сразу к контролеру для авторизации.

```js
if (data != 'undefined') {  
    $scope.data = {'login': data.login, 'phone': data.phone};

var link = 'http://site.ru/login.php';  
$http.get(link, {params: {'login': data.login, 'phone': data.phone}}).then(function(resp) {
                if (resp.data.success == null) {
                    $scope.data = {};
                } else {
                    $state.go("main.tips");
                }
            }, function(err) {
                console.error('ERR', err);
                // err.status will contain the status code
            })

        } else {
            $scope.data = {};
        }
```

Вот таким образом выглядит сам login.php :

```php
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

exit(0);
}

require_once('conection.php');

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
if (isset($postdata)) {
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $login = $request->login;
    $phone = $request->phone;

    $login = $_GET['login'];
    $phone = $_GET['phone'];

    $data = array();


    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE login='{$login}' AND phone='{$phone}' ") or die ('Error : ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    if ($row['id'] === NULL) {
        $data['success'] = 0;
    } else {
        $data['success'] = 1;
    }
}
} else {
echo "Not called properly with username parameter!";
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

В браузере все прекрасно работает, авторизация проходит. Но на реальном девайсе (android) ничего не происходит. Видимо, что-то не так с запросом.

В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В **config.xml** в корне проекта нужно разрешить обращаться куда угодно или же на конкретный домен.
Если мне не изменяет память это делается так:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```